# Why is the circle moving in a straight line instead of at an angle in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning the basics of pygame in my free time at work. I wanted to move the bottom boundary of my program up, but when I changed the boundary collision condition, the ball moves in a straight line instead of at an angle.

When I delete the 525 part of the condition in the bounceCircle definition, it moves as expected. When I place it back, it moves in a horizontal line.

```py
import pygame
import sys
import random
import math

# Initalize the game engine
pygame.init()

# Define common colors:
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# Set window size, title, and background color
(width, height) = (900, 600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Ball Playground")

screen.fill(WHITE)

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Ball class
class Particles():

    def __init__(self, position, radius):
        self.x = position[0]
        self.y = position[1]
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = (BLUE)
        # thickness = 0 means filled
        # thickness > 0 thicker border
        # thickness < 0 nothing
        self.thickness = 1
        self.speed = 0
        self.angle = 0

    # Definition for drawing circle
    def drawCircle(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.radius, self.thickness)

    # Definition for moving the circle
    def moveCircle(self):
        self.x += math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed
        self.y -= math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed

    # Definition for bouncing off of surfaces
    def bounceCircle(self):
        if (self.x > width - self.radius) or (self.x < self.radius):
            self.angle = - self.angle
        elif (self.y > height - self.radius) or (self.y < 525 - self.radius):
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle

ball = Particles((450, 300), 40)

ball.speed = 2

ball.angle = random.uniform(0, math.pi*2)

# --------- Main Program Loop ----------
while True:
    # --- Main Event Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    #--- Game Logic
    ball.moveCircle()
    ball.bounceCircle()
    ball.drawCircle()

    #--- Drawings
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, [0, 525], [900, 525], 2)

    # Prints tiny diaginal lines to mark surface
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 5
    for i in range(0, width):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, [x1, 530], [x2, 525], 2)
        x1 += 5
        x2 += 5

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `bounceCircle` function to:

```
    def bounceCircle(self):
        if (self.x + self.radius > width ) or (self.x - self.radius < 0):
            self.angle = - self.angle
        elif (self.y + self.radius > (525)) or (self.y - self.radius < 0):
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle
```

Whole Code (fixed a few bugs):

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import math

# Initalize the game engine
pygame.init()

# Define common colors:
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# Set window size, title, and background color
(width, height) = (900, 600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Ball Playground")

screen.fill(WHITE)

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Ball class
class Particles():

    def __init__(self, position, radius):
        self.x = position[0]
        self.y = position[1]
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = (BLUE)
        # thickness = 0 means filled
        # thickness > 0 thicker border
        # thickness < 0 nothing
        self.thickness = 1
        self.speed = 0
        self.angle = 0

    # Definition for drawing circle
    def drawCircle(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.radius, self.thickness)

    # Definition for moving the circle
    def moveCircle(self):
        self.x += math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed
        self.y -= math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed
        print(self.angle, self.x, self.y)

    # Definition for bouncing off of surfaces
    def bounceCircle(self):
        if (self.x > width - self.radius) or (self.x < self.radius):
            self.angle = - self.angle
        elif (self.y + self.radius > (height-100)) or (self.y - self.radius < 0):
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle

ball = Particles((450, 300), 40)

ball.speed = 20

ball.angle = random.uniform(0, math.pi*2)
print(ball.angle)
# --------- Main Program Loop ----------
while True:
    # --- Main Event Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    #--- Game Logic
    ball.moveCircle()
    ball.bounceCircle()
    ball.drawCircle()

    #--- Drawings
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [0, 525], [900, 525], 2)

    # Prints tiny diaginal lines to mark surface
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 5
    for i in range(0, width):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLUE, [x1, 530], [x2, 525], 2)
        x1 += 5
        x2 += 5

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```